# How to count a certain character within a file C++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
    inFile.get(file);
    while(inFile) {
       inFile.get(file);
       cout << file;
       if(inFile.fail()) {
          break;
       }
        if(inFile) {
           ++charNum;
        }
         if(inFile && c =='<') {
             ++comNum;
         }
```

The values keep outputting 1, and its not actually counting the amount of < in the file. If I put inFile >> c, it makes my file a bunch of gibberish. What is the best way to count a certain amount of characters within a file, that is being opened by the user? Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say when you just show a random piece from the program. Make it a [mcve].

Comment: I recommend starting with: `char c; while(c = inFile.get())`

Comment: Actually, I recommend creating a large buffer, block read into the buffer and search the buffer.  Repeat as necessary until EOF.  This should be more efficient than reading one character at a time.  For more fun, create multiple buffers.  Read into the first buffer, then start reading into the second buffer.  During the read of the second buffer, search the first buffer.  Yes, this would best be served with multiple threads.

Comment: `if(inFile && c =='<') {` this doesn't read any characters at all. Did you mean to write something like `if(inFile >> c)  if (c =='<') {`, or even better putting the `(inFile >> c) ` as condition of your `while()` loop?

Comment: Whenever I try to do the (inFile >> c) it makes my output gibberish. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @GabeF Though it's a fact that just writing `infile` doesn't read anything from the file at all. You must have a problem elsewhere if adding `infile >> c` to your code breaks your desired output.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? @πάνταῥεῖ Whenever the file is streamed it comes up as gibberish. But my other output is fine. Sorry if I'm not very clear, this is really new to me.

Comment: @GabeF To read from the file character wise? Yes, there are other ways, e.g. using [`std::istream::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (`infile.get(c)`), it returns a reference to the stream you address, and used in a condition, the streams state will be checked. You should note that a EOF condition met doesn't set a streams state to `fail() == true` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate), there's a nifty table overview at the end of that reference page).

Comment: @GabeF Also regarding the _"gibberish"_, what's the character encoding of that file you're trying to read? Is it a plain ASCII text file at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on algorithms provided by the Standard Library.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::ifstream fp(argv[1]);

  const auto count = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{fp},
                                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}, '<');

  std::cout << "count: " << count << "\n";
}
```